# Universal Dashboard powershell calling function System.Management.Automation.Runspace.IntialSessionState

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Hey all I am trying to call a function and have it print out the return with a UDHTML Markup to display it inside the tooltip.

```
Start-UdDashboard -Content {
    $icon_Degraded   = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAASCAMAAABhE=='
    $icon_Advisory   = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAA='
    $icon_Unhealthy  = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'
    $icon_Healthy    = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUkJggg=='

    New-UdDashboard -Title "Server Performance Dashboard" -Color '#FF050F7F' -Content {
        New-UdRow {
            New-UdColumn -Size 6 -Content {
                New-UdRow {
                    New-UdColumn -Size 12 -Content {
                        New-UdTable -Title "Athena Status" -Headers @(" ", " ") -Endpoint {
                            @{'MX PAI Ingestion' = 
                                    New-UDTooltip -TooltipContent {
                                        $EI = New-UDEndpointInitialization -Variable "testing" -Function "Test-It"
                                        new-udhtml -markup $EI
                                    } -content { 
                                        New-UDHTML -Markup "<img src='data:image/png;base64,$icon_Degraded' />"
                                    }
                            }.GetEnumerator() | Out-UDTableData -Property @("Name", "Value")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function Test-It{
        Return "HELLO TO YOU SIR"
    }
}
```

This code works just fine and displays what it needs to but it never displays/calls the Test-It function. Though I do get this inside the tooltip when hovering:

[image]

I've also tried:

```
$EI = New-UDEndpointInitialization -Function “Test-It”
new-udhtml -markup $EI

$EI = New-UDEndpointInitialization -Function “Test-It”
New-UDCard -Title “The Title” -Endpoint {$EI}
```

So powershell gurus - what am I missing?

Comment: This is not a Powershell issue per see but rather an issue with the "Powershell Universal" product and how this specific bit was implemented.  I recommend you to ask on the PSU forums instead.  https://forums.ironmansoftware.com/ .  People there, including Adam (creator of PSU) are very active.

Comment: @SagePourpre Alright I will do that. I will also leave this question here just in case someone else can contribute to it.